# GHC doesn't pick the only available instance

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

I'm trying to write a CSS DSL in Haskell, and keep the syntax as close to CSS as possible. One difficulty is that certain terms can appear both as a property and value. For example flex: you can have "display: flex" and "flex: 1" in CSS.

I've let myself inspire by the Lucid API, which overrides functions based on the function arguments to generate either attributes or DOM nodes (which sometimes also share names, eg `<style>` and `<div style="...">`).

Anyway, I've ran into a problem that GHC fails to typecheck the code (Ambiguous type variable), in a place where it is supposed to pick one of the two available typeclass instances. There is only one instance which fits (and indeed, in the type error GHC prints "These potential instance exist:" and then it lists just one). I'm confused that given the choice of a single instance, GHC refuses to use it. Of course, if I add explicit type annotations then the code compiles. Full example below (only dependency is mtl, for Writer).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Style where

import Control.Monad.Writer.Lazy


type StyleM = Writer [(String, String)]
newtype Style = Style { runStyle :: StyleM () }


class Term a where
    term :: String -> a

instance Term String where
    term = id

instance Term (String -> StyleM ()) where
    term property value = tell [(property, value)]


display :: String -> StyleM ()
display = term "display"

flex :: Term a => a
flex = term "flex"

someStyle :: Style
someStyle = Style $ do
    flex "1"     -- [1] :: StyleM ()
    display flex -- [2]
```

And the error:

```
Style.hs:29:5: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘flex’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Term
                                  ([Char]
                                   -> WriterT
                                        [(String, String)]
                                        Data.Functor.Identity.Identity
                                        a0))’ from being solved.
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        one instance involving out-of-scope types
          instance Term (String -> StyleM ()) -- Defined at Style.hs:17:10
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: flex "1"
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do { flex "1";
              display flex }’
      In the expression:
        Style
        $ do { flex "1";
               display flex }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I've found two ways how to make this code compile, none of which I'm happy with.

1. Add explicit annotation where the flex function is used ([1]).
2. Move the line where flex is used to the end of the do block (eg. comment out [2]).

One difference between my API and Lucid is that the Lucid terms always take one argument, and Lucid uses fundeps, which presumably gives the GHC typechecker more information to work with (to choose the correct typeclass instance). But in my case the terms don't always have an argument (when they appear as the value).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the `Term` instance for `String -> StyleM ()` only exists when `StyleM` is parameterized with `()`. But in a do-block like

```
someStyle :: Style
someStyle = Style $ do
    flex "1"
    return ()
```

there is not enough information to know which is the type parameter in `flex "1"`, because the return value is thrown away.

A common solution to this problem is the ["constraint trick"](http://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick). It requires type equality constraints, so you have to enable `{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}`
 or `{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}` and tweak the instance like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

instance (a ~ ()) => Term (String -> StyleM a) where
    term property value = tell [(property, value)]
```

This tells the compiler: "You don't need to know the precise type `a` to get the instance, there is one for all types! However, once the instance is determined, you'll *always* find that the type was `()` after all!"

This trick is the typeclass version of Henry Ford's "You can have any color you like, as long as it's black." The compiler can find an instance *despite* the ambiguity, and finding the instance gives him enough information to *resolve* the ambiguity.

It works because Haskell's instance resolution *never* backtracks, so once an instance "matches", the compiler has to commit to any equalities it discovers in the preconditions of the instance declaration, or throw a type error.

Comment: Ooh, that's neat.

Comment: Is this constraint trick in the SO Documentation for Haskell? It seems to come up fairly often. I know I've used it in several answers and comments.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not sure. Also the name "constraint trick" is overly general and makes it sound like, well, a trick. Would something like "instance resolution can drive type inference" be better?

Comment: Unfortunately the line with `flex "1"` still causes problems when I enable OverloadedStrings.

You mentioned that instance resolution doesn't backtrack. But what about type inference? GHC could try with the most obvious choice for `"1"`, which is `String` and then try to infer the other types based on that.

Comment: @wereHamster To solve the problem with OverloadedStrings, perhaps you can try the "constraint trick" for a second time: `instance (a ~ (),s ~ String) => Term (s -> StyleM a)`. Resolving the instance will inform the typechecker that `a` must be `()` and `s` must be `String`.

Comment: @wereHamster "GHC could try with the most obvious choice for `1`, which is String and then try to infer the other types based on that." But then if you later added a `Term (Text -> StyleM a)` instance, that would create an ambiguity. As Reid Barton said, "GHC never assumes that it knows about all instances, when checking a use of a type class". This conservative approach ensures that existing code won't change behaviour or cease to compile because someone added a new instance elsewhere in your program, or in a library.

Comment: @danidiaz The trick with the second constraint helped. Thanks a lot! Now I can move forward with the actual implementation of the library :)

Answer (score 6):

> There is only one instance which fits (and indeed, in the type error GHC prints "These potential instance exist:" and then it lists just one). I'm confused that given the choice of a single instance, GHC refuses to use it.

Type classes are open; any module could define new instances. So GHC never assumes that it knows about *all* instances, when checking a use of a type class. (With the possible exception of the bad extensions like `OverlappingInstances`.) Logically, then, the only possible answers to a question "is there an instance for `C T`" are "yes" and "I don't know". To answer "no" risks incoherence with another part of your program that does define an instance `C T`.

So, you should not imagine the compiler iterating over every declared instance and seeing whether it fits at the particular use site of interest, because what would it do with all the "I don't know"s? Instead, the process works like this: infer the most general type that could be used at the particular use site and *query* the instance store for the needed instance. The query can return a more general instance than the one needed, but it can never return a more specific instance, since it would have to choose which more specific instance to return; then your program is ambiguous.

One way to think about the difference is that iterating over all declared instances for `C` would take linear time in the number of instances, while querying the instance store for a specific instance only has to examine a constant number of potential instances. For example, if I want to type check

`Left True == Left False`

I need an instance for `Eq (Either Bool t)`, which can only be satisfied by one of

```
instance Eq (Either Bool t)
instance Eq (Either a t)    -- *
instance Eq (f Bool t)
instance Eq (f a t)
instance Eq (g t)
instance Eq b
```

(The instance marked `*` is the one that actually exists, and in standard Haskell (without `FlexibleInstances`) it's the *only* one of these instances that is legal to declare; the traditional restriction to instances of the form `C (T var1 ... varN)` makes this step easy since there will always be exactly one potential instance.)

If instances are stored in something like a hash table then this query can be done in constant time regardless of the number of declared instances of `Eq` (which is probably a pretty large number).

In this step, only instance heads (the stuff to the right of the `=>`) are examined. Along with a "yes" answer, the instance store can return new constraints on type variables that come from the context of the instance (the stuff to the left of the `=>`). These constraints then need to be solved in the same manner. (This is why instances are considered to overlap if they have overlapping heads, even if their contexts look mutually exclusive, and why `instance Foo a => Bar a` is almost never a good idea.)

In your case, since a value of any type can be discarded in `do` notation, we need an instance for `Term (String -> StyleM a)`. The instance `Term (String -> StyleM ())` is more specific, so it's useless in this case. You could either write

```
do
  () <- flex "1"
  ...
```

to make the needed instance more specific, or make the provided instance more general by using the type equality trick as explained in danidiaz's answer.

Comment: I think saying that fully polymorphic instances are almost never a good idea goes a bit too far. Fully polymorphic instances of custom classes can be very useful. They're pretty commonly used to bundle many constraints into a single one, and are often necessary for using machinery like `Data.Constraint.Forall`. That said, fully polymorphic instances of standard classes are absolutely terrible.

Comment: That's the "almost". And nowadays you can write a type synonym for the constraints.

Comment: >  Logically, then, the only possible answers to a question "is there an instance for C T" are "yes" and "I don't know". 

That question though is a precondition to be able to compile the code. And the compiler can not say "I don't know" when you ask it whether it can compile code or not. Or rather, "I don't know" is the same as "No", because the output is binary: Either I get an executable or not.

Comment: If your program needs an instance `C T` to compile then an "I don't know" answer is the same as a "no" answer, yes. But if your program needs an instance to *not* exist in order to compile, then you can never be sure that the instance does not exist. In your example, you need the nonexistence of instances like `String -> StyleM Bool` (which could have totally different behavior!) in order to not be ambiguous.